# document.querySelectorAll(variable class)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I just find that document.getElementsByClassName() is not available for IE8. For this reason I want use document.querySelectorAll(), but my real problem is that class name come in a varible, and can't get the result of the function. Like this:

```
var linea = document.querySelectorAll(revisados[i].value);
```

My function is triggered by an checkbox by an onchange(value), and when the execution check the parameter value of querySelectorAll fail. I tried:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" onchange="javascript:name(this)" />
```

The value is a class for many other elements.
And the JS:

```
function name(param){
var className=param.value;
var class2 = "."+class;
var linea = document.querySelectorAll("."+param); //doesn't work
var linea = document.querySelectorAll("."+className); //doesn't work
var linea = document.querySelectorAll("."+className.value); //doesn'twork
var linea = document.querySelectorAll(class2); //doesn'twork
var linea = document.querySelectorAll(String(class)); //doesn't work
}
```

Please any suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know if it is intentional but you have typed `onchage` instead of `onchange`. Also, you can not use `class` as a javascript variable name because it will produce  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word`.

Comment: FYI, the `javascript:` part in your inline event handler is completely unnecessary. I recommend to remove it to not spread the false impression that it is required.

Comment: it is a not intentional mistake. I know that "class" is a reserved word, just try to express my problem clearly. It is not the code of my real function, is an example only.

Comment: @h3g0r_: How should we be able to distinguish between problems in your actual code and problems in the example? An example should only replicate your actual problems, not introduce new problems.

Comment: Why did you even try to use `document.querySelectorAll("."+param);`? What do you expect from concatenating a DOM Element with a string? Similar for `document.querySelectorAll("."+className.value);`. Strings don't have a `value` property. I feel you would benefit from refreshing some JS basics. I mean, trying things out is good, but it seems like you blindly tried every possible combination. Maybe take a step back and read some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDocument.querySelector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `querySelector`

```
function name(param){
var classValue=param.value;
linea = document.querySelector("."+classValue); 
console.log(linea.length)
}
```

Also IE8 does not allow CSS class to begin with a digit.

Comment: I got a SyntaxError too. :(

Comment: Do you have any element in your HTML with class name `1`?

Comment: Yes, of course. If with getElementsByClassName() works on IE9+. The problem is when  I  tried get de element with document.querySelectorAll(variable)  :(

Comment: `querySelect` returns a single DOM element, so `linea.length` will return `undefined` in the best case and throw a runtime error in the worst case.

Comment: @h3g0r_: IE8 may not allow CSS class names to start with digits.

Comment: @FelixKling maybe you're right, In my quickly test works with a "word_1" clase name. I hope yes

Comment: yeah, that was. Thank you very much @FelixKling

Comment: I have ((updated) mentioned that what FelixKling told. If it solves your problem please consider voting it up and marking it as correct answer.