# How can I use a variable in a query selector?

Tags: javascript

Here's my html element

```
    <div class="rands rando1"></div>
```

And here's my attempt at styling the element with a variable in the query selector

```
    var selector = 'rando1';
    document.querySelector(selector).style.width = "50%";
```

It throws this error

```
    Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/app.js:51
```

Comment: it should be var selector = ".rando1"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [document.querySelectorAll(variable class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704100/document-queryselectorallvariable-class)

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+variable+selector+site:stackoverflow.com)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `querySelector`, you have to add the css prefix before.

If it's a class, change your variable to '.rando1'

Comment: Please do not answer such simple typo-type questions. There WILL be a dupe and OP should delete the question

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at this. How does answering their question cause any harm?

Comment: It stops the asker from deleting the question and learn to investigate before asking. There are [SO MANY DUPES](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+variable+selector+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I'm interested in learning more, but I think your link is broken?

Comment: No it is not. It is just a google search for `javascript variable selector site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. Well good to know. I would have commented instead, but I don't have enough rep yet unfortunately.

Comment: @mplungjan i did attempt to fix the issue. But i didn't know it was syntax issue. Thanks anyway.